# Posting data with curl - actually refreshing to the next page

Tags: php, post, curl

I'm trying to send post data between pages with Post. Not a form - like I may be passing validation error between pages or something (using it in several places).

The cURL is executing fine, but it's just tacking on the new page at the bottom. How can I execute a cURL Post and load the following page?

So my goal is to send data between pages. I do not want to use GET or cookies as I do not want to rely on the user, and I'd prefer not to use $_SESSION as it is not so much directly about a session as sending private data between pages.

Thanks

```
$ch = curl_init($some_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'myvar=something');
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I doubt the code has any relevance, as it's about performing a task not code syntax (there may be one in this example but you'll have to trust me it's not the code that's buggy as it's retrieving fine).

Comment: Hmm, this approach sounds complicated. Is there a strong argument against using `$_SESSION` to store information between page requests?

Comment: You are going to have to show us some code before we have any idea what you mean/where the problem lies.

Comment: @rjz I've felt that $_SESSION is for things related to a particular user 'profile', and I want to use $_POST because I'm sending not-particularly-individual data (eg after a form is submitted, the errors are checked and if there are any, it is sent back to the original page, which checks if any errors have been sent back and outputs them if so).

DaveRandom, code is unnessary; as I recently learned cURL is for getting the data; curl_exec($handle) retrieves the handle page but does not actually go to it. But if you wish, I included the code.

Comment: Hey @Raeki, `$_SESSION`s are a pretty common place to store the kind of "flash data" you describe, as well. There isn't any reason you can't have a key in your session corresponding to the user and a key corresponding to any validation errors

Comment: @rjz Ah, after searching fruitlessly for several days I think I'll just go with the $_SESSION. I still feel like a post would be more 'proper'/'defined' so if anyone knows a workaround (there desn't seem to be a clean one) please let me know! rjz if you want to post an answer you've been the most helpful

Comment: Hey @Raeki, sorry I couldn't be more help—I've posted an answer showing how I'd go about setting this up with `$_SESSION`...good luck, though, however you end up approaching it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could separate your `$_SESSION` superglobal into arrays describing both the current user/session and any errors that your form has created. For instance,

```
$_SESSION = array(
  'user' => array(), // user data goes here
  'errors' => array() // validation data goes here
);

if (!$_POST['myvar'] == 'something') {
  $_SESSION['errors']['myvar'] = 'You must specify a value for <code>myvar</code>';
}
```

You would then be able to output errors on subsequent pages using a call something like this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['errors'])) {
  foreach($_SESSION['errors'] as $error) {
    echo '<li>' . $error . '</li>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using cURL?  Why not just use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$(function() {

   // Send data asynchronously
   $.ajax({
      url: '/path/to/your/script.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: 'var1=value1&var2'=$('input.some_class').val(),
      success: function(data) {
         // Send the user to another page
         window.location.href = '/to/infinity/and/beyond';
      }
   });

});
```

Comment: I'm using PHP, and would prefer to stay away from Javascript (for reliance on the user - whether they have it enabled or not for example, and I just want to keep as much of the performance under my own control and hide unnesesary information)

Answer (score 0):

Using ajax for exec

```
$(function() {

   /
      data: 'var1=value1&/ Send data asynchronously
   $.ajax({
      url: '/path/to/your/script.php',
      type: 'POST',var2'=$('input.some_class').val(),
      success: function(data) {
         // Send the user to another page
         window.location.href = '/to/infinity/and/beyond';
      }
   });

});
```